# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: angular

I am trying to display an API using *ngFor in frontend. But I am getting this error.
"Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'."
data is coming in console.
My ts code,

```
posts = [] //problem lies here I guess
  constructor(private user:UsersService) 
  {
    this.user.getData().subscribe(data=>{
      console.warn(data); // uptill here code works
      this.posts = data; // and here
    })
  }
```

my frontend code,

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>User Id</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <td>{{post.id}}</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>User Id</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: data that your binding does not have property called id

Comment: Can you show the log of `this.post`

Comment: mark my answer as answer to question

Answer (score 0):

try following code. try to declare posts as any type

```
posts:any;
```

Comment: uptill now I was doing this, posts:any[]   and this, posts = [].

Comment: @user8751821 did you mark my answer as not useful? it decreased my reputation. mark it as answer to question.